# Insert a new column on text file based on Filename value

Tags: python, methods, apache-spark, text-files

I've 10 text files with 3 columns. The filename is the date that each file was created. I want to add a new column (name "Date") on each file based on the file title.

How can I do that in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
files = ["20150612.txt", ...]

for file in files:
    with open(file, "a") as f:
        f.write("\nname \"" + file[:-4] + "\"")
```

It is a bit hacky but for such a small problem a more robust solution is not necessary.

Explanation:

open file in mode `a`ppend and write `\n` (which is a newline), `name` and the date surrounded by quotes.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for your response!

But I'm not seeing any new column on my files. I just write your code

Comment: Have you checked that the files in `files` are correct? Maybe try with a simple file with only `test` in it and see if that works, because on my machine this is working.